# How to use stream_rails with Angular UI/Serialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, getstream-io

I was wondering if Stream.io's stream_rails gem, is actually getting the records of the resource. say User: 1, will get user record with id: 1 from the PostGreSQL(in my case) DB, however I need to render the UI in AngularJS Frontend, instead of rails, how would I do that? can I still do the smart finding form way that stream_rails does it where it uses the rendered activity feed type(aggregated,flat,notification) to render the feed? is there some angular thing out there? Also, on top of that I'm using AMS to serialize my data into JSON to be sent to the client, will AMS pick up on the rendered activities and serialize the model records in the rendered activities? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `is there some angular thing out there?` -- this is too vague of a question to answer.

Comment: (1) How does `stream_rails` work? (2) How do I build an AngularJS front-end for a Rails app? (3) Is there an existing implementation of this? (4) Does `stream_rails` integrate with AMS?

Comment: Those are four very broad questions... I think this is way beyond the scope of a single SO post.

Answer (score 0):

The stream_rails gem has documentation for "enriching" the feed data to turn your actor from "user:123" back into a User object for "Derek" and whatever other data that might contain, same for any other activity fields you specify in the enrichment setup. From there you can have your Rails controller action return a json payload that your Angular app can interpret and draw your UI.